# Usando PHPMailer para envio de email com anexo mas sem usar Usuário e Senha

Tags: php, email

Essa foi a unica forma que eu consegui fazer. Quando eu tiro a configuração SSL ele não envia. Queria uma forma que não utilizasse SMTP, vocês podem me ajudar?

Meu código até o momento:

```
require("phpmail/class.phpmailer.php");
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();                        
$mail->Host = '';         
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;   
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
$mail->Port = 465;
$mail->Username = 'contato@scribblingideas.com.br';
$mail->Password = 'senha';
$mail->From = 'remetente@dominio.com.br';
$mail->FromName = 'Fale conosco';
$mail->AddAddress($destinatario);
$mail->IsHTML(true); 
$mail->Subject = "Fale conosco";`
```

Answer (score 3):

Substitua:

```php
$mail->IsSMTP();                        
$mail->Host = '';         
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;   
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
$mail->Port = 465;
$mail->Username = 'contato@scribblingideas.com.br';
$mail->Password = 'senha';
```

por:

```php
$mail->IsMail();
```

e pronto, mas para poder testar usando o método mail você deve ter seu arquivo hospedado em um servidor com suporte a php.